# Using pipe operators in "ggplot2movies" (R)

Tags: r, command-line

I'm just getting started with R and I need your help. I'm working with the `movies` dataset from the `ggplot2movies` package and I need to use just one long pipe command to create the following dataset: filter movies after 1995, select all variables
besides `Comedy`, `Romance`, and `Short`, group by `Drama` and `Action` and create the mean rating. I managed to get it to work, but I've been using multiple pipe commands for that:

```
movies%>%
  filter(year>1995)%>%
  select(!Short,!Comedy,!Romance)%>%
  group_by(Drama,Action)%>%
  summarise(mean_rating=mean(rating))
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to convert this into a single operation? The help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think 'One long pipe command' is what you already have.  Can you explain a little more about why a different format is needed if your current code works?

Comment: If you want to do it in a single line it would be something like `summarise(group_by(select(filter(movies, year>1995), !Short,!Comedy,!Romance), Drama,Action), mean_rating=mean(rating))`

Comment: So the reason why I need to do this is simply because my teacher requested it as part of an exercise. I think he wants us to only use ```%>%``` once and have a combined function like h(g(f(x))). I hope it makes sense!

Comment: Yes @benson23, that's right. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Up to interpretation of course, but „one long pipe command“ for me means what you already have, i.e. you start with your input data (movies) and then pipe through until the end without creating any intermediate object. But could easily mean sth. else.

Comment: I agree with @deschen, `summarise(group_by(select(filter(movies, year>1995), !Short,!Comedy,!Romance), Drama,Action), mean_rating=mean(rating))` does not contain a pipe command. If your instructor is specifically requesting a pipe command this may not be what they want - the `%>%` is the pipe. But the above code is great for brevity if they are not specifically requesting a pipe

Comment: Although, educationally, requesting such a code does not make sense, because it lacks readability and doing it the usual several-pipes way shows the steps much better (unless the learning goal is to show how you can nest commands into each other). But this is highly OT now.